# apktool decompiler missing xml files in res folder

Tags: android

I am using apktool to decompile the apk to get the res file. I downloaded the apktool and used command (apktool –d myapp.apk), it is extracting the res file but in value folder some xml files are missing.Please let me know the solution.Thanks..

Comment: if you used like `strings.xml` and `strings-extra.xml` it will combine all those to a single xml because info about source files is not stored. Possible that the values you don't find are in one of those existing xml files?

Comment: Hi..I verified.. these values are not available in other xml also. In public.xml all string decreation are available.So when i try to build apk (using apktool –b myapp) even without any modification, i am getting error like "Public symbol string/xyz declared here is not defined".

Answer (score 1):

Just open APK with Winrar and you'll find the stuff there.

Comment: Apktool should decode the values. What does it say when you use `apktool –d myapp.apk`? There should be a line that says: `Decoding values*/* XMLs…`.

Comment: It doesn't give any error in decompile using apktool. But some xml files is not available in res file. When i try to create apk(apktool –b myapp) even without any modification it give me error "Public symbol string/xyz declared here is not defined".

Comment: It may be missing from the APK.

Comment: Hi.. I am decompling and building working myapp.apk.. I wanted to add some aj files to the code. But i am not even getting compiled apk without any change. I have using just tow command.1. apktool –d myapp.apk 2. apktool –b myapp, its decompiling without any error.but while building apk it is showing error like "Public symbol string/xyz declared here is not defined".

Answer (score 1):

The error "Public symbol string/xyz declared here is not defined" is telling you that the edit you made is not defined in the string.xml. You will have to edit the string.xml also.

Comment: Also, using winrar will not show you the values folder because the values folder is a part of the resources.arsc file in the apk

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to the issue tracked [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/issues/detail?)!

A more interesting point about this problem is explained by owner of apktool2.0 beta release [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/issues/detail?id=441#20)!

I get a feeling that the problem you are facing is because of the apk being built using older aapt and you are building using newer aapt. Try getting the aapt version using which the apk was built and see if apktool helps your case.